# how to make multiple inline dropdown lists cross platform compatible?

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to put two inline dropdown lists. I tested and it works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but IE9 (ofcourse) is not liking it. It puts the second dropdown list right below the first one. This is what my html and css looks like:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="region-path">
    <div id="region-dropdown">
            <!-- <form name="regionform" action=""> -->
            <form action="">
                    <!-- <select id="regionselection" > -->
                    <select id="regionDropDown">
                        <option value="0" selected="selected">All Regions</option>
                        @foreach (var region in Model.RegionData)
                        {
                            <option value="@region.regionID"> @region.regionName</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                    <!-- <input type="button" id="submitButton" value="Submit" /> -->
            </form>
     </div>

    <div id="path-dropdown">
        <form action="">
            <select>
                <option value="0" selected="selected">All Paths</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#region-path 
{
    margin: 20px 35px;
}

#region-dropdown, #path-dropdown
{
    display: inline-block;    
    width: 160px;
}

#path-dropdown
{
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

How can I fix this? I am very new to web development, so point out if I am doing something else wrong too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to play around with it a little bit and finally fixed it:

```
#region-path 
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px 35px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 20px;
}

#region-dropdown, #path-dropdown
{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;   
    width: 90px;
    height: 19px;
}

#path-dropdown
{
    left: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears correctly in IE9, so long as IE is not in IE9 compatibility mode.

The issue lies in that IE7 (which is, for the purposes of this question, the same as IE9 compatibility mode) doesn't understand `inline-block` for `display`. You can use `display:inline` with layout trick to fix this.

```
display:inline-block; /* for browsers that don't suck */
*display:inline; /* ignored by most browsers except IE7 */
zoom:1; /* you can't set dimensions on an inline element in IE<7, which is to be expected, UNLESS it has layout. zoom will do this */
```

The result is that compliant browsers will see `inline-block` and display correctly, where IE7 will see an inline element, but since it has layout, you can give it a height or width.

Here's a functional example. Use the developer toolbar to switch different modes and you should see it works in all. http://jsfiddle.net/7uSbR/1/

Comment: thanks bro but neither visual studio nor IE9 liked `*display` and `zoom`. I even try turning the compatibility mode on/off but no effects. However after playing with it for a little bit, I was able to fix it. :-)

Comment: VS will complain but that doesn't matter. I use that approach a lot, and did verify on my machine before I posted so I'm not sure why it didn't work for you.

Comment: freakin VS lol. Yeah I mean I checked in jsfiddle as well and it seems to be fine but for some reason IE9 didn't do much except lining up the second dropdown list right below the first one.